# Banshee Freezing on import media files

Tags: 16.04, banshee

When I've started to import media files, banshee just frozen. Tried to run on terminal to pick more information and it returned these messages:

```
luis@jupiter:~$ banshee
[Info  08:36:24.468] Running Banshee 2.6.2: [Ubuntu 16.04 LTS (linux-gnu, x86_64) @ 2016-04-18 13:50:09 UTC]
[Warn  08:36:24.736] Não é possível conectar-se ao NetworkManager ou Wicd - Será assumido que há uma conexão de rede disponível e em funcionamento

(Banshee:2237): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: attempting to add an interface (AtkComponent) to class (__gtksharp_49_Hyena_Gui_BaseWidgetAccessible) after class_init

(Banshee:2237): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: attempting to add an interface (AtkSelection) to class (__gtksharp_50_Hyena_Data_Gui_Accessibility_ListViewAccessible+601+5b+5bBanshee_Collection_TrackInfo+2c+20Banshee_Core+2c+20Version+3d2_6_0_0+2c+20Culture+3dneutral+2c+20PublicKeyToken+3dnull+5d+5d) after class_init

(Banshee:2237): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: attempting to add an interface (AtkTable) to class (__gtksharp_50_Hyena_Data_Gui_Accessibility_ListViewAccessible+601+5b+5bBanshee_Collection_TrackInfo+2c+20Banshee_Core+2c+20Version+3d2_6_0_0+2c+20Culture+3dneutral+2c+20PublicKeyToken+3dnull+5d+5d) after class_init
[Warn  08:36:25.056] Initialization of accessibility support for ListView widgets failed - System.ArgumentException: Invalid signal name: model_changed (in `glib-sharp')
  at GLib.Signal.Emit (GLib.Object instance, System.String detailed_signal, System.Object[] args) <0x40e11a60 + 0x004df> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Hyena.Data.Gui.Accessibility.ListViewAccessible`1[T].EmitModelChanged () <0x40e119e0 + 0x0003b> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Hyena.ThreadAssist.ProxyToMain (Hyena.InvokeHandler handler) <0x40e11910 + 0x00037> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Hyena.Data.Gui.Accessibility.ListViewAccessible`1[T].OnModelChanged (System.Object o, System.EventArgs a) <0x40e11820 + 0x000d3> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Hyena.Data.Gui.Accessibility.ListViewAccessible`1[T]..ctor (GLib.Object widget) <0x40e0c3e0 + 0x0045f> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Hyena.Data.Gui.ListViewAccessibleFactory`1[T].Init () <0x40e0b2a0 + 0x00093> in <filename unknown>:0 

(Banshee:2237): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: attempting to add an interface (AtkSelection) to class (__gtksharp_55_Hyena_Data_Gui_Accessibility_ListViewAccessible+601+5b+5bBanshee_Collection_Database_QueryFilterInfo+601+5b+5bSystem_String+2c+20mscorlib+2c+20Version+3d4_0_0_0+2c+20Culture+3dneutral+2c+20PublicKeyToken+3db77a5c561934e089+5d+5d+2c+20Banshee_Services+2c+20Version+3d2_6_0_0+2c+20Culture+3dneutral+2c+20PublicKeyToken+3dnull+5d+5d) after class_init

(Banshee:2237): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: attempting to add an interface (AtkTable) to class (__gtksharp_55_Hyena_Data_Gui_Accessibility_ListViewAccessible+601+5b+5bBanshee_Collection_Database_QueryFilterInfo+601+5b+5bSystem_String+2c+20mscorlib+2c+20Version+3d4_0_0_0+2c+20Culture+3dneutral+2c+20PublicKeyToken+3db77a5c561934e089+5d+5d+2c+20Banshee_Services+2c+20Version+3d2_6_0_0+2c+20Culture+3dneutral+2c+20PublicKeyToken+3dnull+5d+5d) after class_init
[Warn  08:36:25.086] Initialization of accessibility support for ListView widgets failed - System.ArgumentException: Invalid signal name: model_changed (in `glib-sharp')
  at GLib.Signal.Emit (GLib.Object instance, System.String detailed_signal, System.Object[] args) <0x40e11a60 + 0x004df> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Hyena.Data.Gui.Accessibility.ListViewAccessible`1[T].EmitModelChanged () <0x40e119e0 + 0x0003b> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Hyena.ThreadAssist.ProxyToMain (Hyena.InvokeHandler handler) <0x40e11910 + 0x00037> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Hyena.Data.Gui.Accessibility.ListViewAccessible`1[T].OnModelChanged (System.Object o, System.EventArgs a) <0x40e11820 + 0x000d3> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Hyena.Data.Gui.Accessibility.ListViewAccessible`1[T]..ctor (GLib.Object widget) <0x40e0c3e0 + 0x0045f> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Hyena.Data.Gui.ListViewAccessibleFactory`1[T].Init () <0x40e0b2a0 + 0x00093> in <filename unknown>:0 

(Banshee:2237): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: attempting to add an interface (AtkSelection) to class (__gtksharp_60_Hyena_Data_Gui_Accessibility_ListViewAccessible+601+5b+5bBanshee_Collection_ArtistInfo+2c+20Banshee_Core+2c+20Version+3d2_6_0_0+2c+20Culture+3dneutral+2c+20PublicKeyToken+3dnull+5d+5d) after class_init

(Banshee:2237): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: attempting to add an interface (AtkTable) to class (__gtksharp_60_Hyena_Data_Gui_Accessibility_ListViewAccessible+601+5b+5bBanshee_Collection_ArtistInfo+2c+20Banshee_Core+2c+20Version+3d2_6_0_0+2c+20Culture+3dneutral+2c+20PublicKeyToken+3dnull+5d+5d) after class_init
[Warn  08:36:25.095] Initialization of accessibility support for ListView widgets failed - System.ArgumentException: Invalid signal name: model_changed (in `glib-sharp')
  at GLib.Signal.Emit (GLib.Object instance, System.String detailed_signal, System.Object[] args) <0x40e11a60 + 0x004df> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Hyena.Data.Gui.Accessibility.ListViewAccessible`1[T].EmitModelChanged () <0x40e119e0 + 0x0003b> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Hyena.ThreadAssist.ProxyToMain (Hyena.InvokeHandler handler) <0x40e11910 + 0x00037> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Hyena.Data.Gui.Accessibility.ListViewAccessible`1[T].OnModelChanged (System.Object o, System.EventArgs a) <0x40e11820 + 0x000d3> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Hyena.Data.Gui.Accessibility.ListViewAccessible`1[T]..ctor (GLib.Object widget) <0x40e0c3e0 + 0x0045f> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Hyena.Data.Gui.ListViewAccessibleFactory`1[T].Init () <0x40e0b2a0 + 0x00093> in <filename unknown>:0 

(Banshee:2237): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: attempting to add an interface (AtkSelection) to class (__gtksharp_65_Hyena_Data_Gui_Accessibility_ListViewAccessible+601+5b+5bBanshee_Collection_YearInfo+2c+20Banshee_Core+2c+20Version+3d2_6_0_0+2c+20Culture+3dneutral+2c+20PublicKeyToken+3dnull+5d+5d) after class_init

(Banshee:2237): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: attempting to add an interface (AtkTable) to class (__gtksharp_65_Hyena_Data_Gui_Accessibility_ListViewAccessible+601+5b+5bBanshee_Collection_YearInfo+2c+20Banshee_Core+2c+20Version+3d2_6_0_0+2c+20Culture+3dneutral+2c+20PublicKeyToken+3dnull+5d+5d) after class_init
[Warn  08:36:25.098] Initialization of accessibility support for ListView widgets failed - System.ArgumentException: Invalid signal name: model_changed (in `glib-sharp')
  at GLib.Signal.Emit (GLib.Object instance, System.String detailed_signal, System.Object[] args) <0x40e11a60 + 0x004df> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Hyena.Data.Gui.Accessibility.ListViewAccessible`1[T].EmitModelChanged () <0x40e119e0 + 0x0003b> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Hyena.ThreadAssist.ProxyToMain (Hyena.InvokeHandler handler) <0x40e11910 + 0x00037> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Hyena.Data.Gui.Accessibility.ListViewAccessible`1[T].OnModelChanged (System.Object o, System.EventArgs a) <0x40e11820 + 0x000d3> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Hyena.Data.Gui.Accessibility.ListViewAccessible`1[T]..ctor (GLib.Object widget) <0x40e0c3e0 + 0x0045f> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Hyena.Data.Gui.ListViewAccessibleFactory`1[T].Init () <0x40e0b2a0 + 0x00093> in <filename unknown>:0 

(Banshee:2237): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: attempting to add an interface (AtkSelection) to class (__gtksharp_70_Hyena_Data_Gui_Accessibility_ListViewAccessible+601+5b+5bBanshee_Collection_AlbumInfo+2c+20Banshee_Core+2c+20Version+3d2_6_0_0+2c+20Culture+3dneutral+2c+20PublicKeyToken+3dnull+5d+5d) after class_init

(Banshee:2237): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: attempting to add an interface (AtkTable) to class (__gtksharp_70_Hyena_Data_Gui_Accessibility_ListViewAccessible+601+5b+5bBanshee_Collection_AlbumInfo+2c+20Banshee_Core+2c+20Version+3d2_6_0_0+2c+20Culture+3dneutral+2c+20PublicKeyToken+3dnull+5d+5d) after class_init
[Warn  08:36:25.102] Initialization of accessibility support for ListView widgets failed - System.ArgumentException: Invalid signal name: model_changed (in `glib-sharp')
  at GLib.Signal.Emit (GLib.Object instance, System.String detailed_signal, System.Object[] args) <0x40e11a60 + 0x004df> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Hyena.Data.Gui.Accessibility.ListViewAccessible`1[T].EmitModelChanged () <0x40e119e0 + 0x0003b> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Hyena.ThreadAssist.ProxyToMain (Hyena.InvokeHandler handler) <0x40e11910 + 0x00037> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Hyena.Data.Gui.Accessibility.ListViewAccessible`1[T].OnModelChanged (System.Object o, System.EventArgs a) <0x40e11820 + 0x000d3> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Hyena.Data.Gui.Accessibility.ListViewAccessible`1[T]..ctor (GLib.Object widget) <0x40e0c3e0 + 0x0045f> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Hyena.Data.Gui.ListViewAccessibleFactory`1[T].Init () <0x40e0b2a0 + 0x00093> in <filename unknown>:0 
[Warn  08:36:25.189] Caught an exception - System.ApplicationException: No support GNOME Settings Daemon could be reached. (in `Banshee.MultimediaKeys')
  at Banshee.MultimediaKeys.MultimediaKeysService.Banshee.ServiceStack.IExtensionService.Initialize () <0x40e3b850 + 0x0037f> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Banshee.ServiceStack.ServiceManager.StartExtension (Mono.Addins.TypeExtensionNode node) <0x40e3b330 + 0x00169> in <filename unknown>:0 
[Warn  08:36:25.189] Extension `Banshee.MultimediaKeys.MultimediaKeysService' not started: No support GNOME Settings Daemon could be reached.
[Info  08:36:25.258] Updating web proxy from GConf
[Warn  08:36:25.291] Caught an exception - System.ApplicationException: No support GNOME Settings Daemon could be reached. (in `Banshee.MultimediaKeys')
  at Banshee.MultimediaKeys.MultimediaKeysService.Banshee.ServiceStack.IExtensionService.Initialize () <0x40e3b850 + 0x0037f> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Banshee.ServiceStack.ServiceManager.StartExtension (Mono.Addins.TypeExtensionNode node) <0x40e3b330 + 0x00169> in <filename unknown>:0 
[Warn  08:36:25.291] Extension `Banshee.MultimediaKeys.MultimediaKeysService' not started: No support GNOME Settings Daemon could be reached.
[Info  08:36:25.292] All services are started 0,675663
[Info  08:36:25.545] AmazonMP3 store redirect URL: http://integrated-services.banshee.fm/amz/redirect.do/
[Info  08:36:25.711] nereid Client Started
[Info  08:36:25.743] GStreamer version 1.8.0.0, gapless: True, replaygain: False
^C
```

At the start of media import, the banshee and dialog windows just froze. Console also stop output messages.

Comment: I've just found a [launchpad bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/banshee/+bug/1533480) probably related this issue.

Comment: Import works by deactivating the podcast feature!

Comment: The latest banshee release was in 2014. Is it the reason to ubuntu not natively comes with banshee? Well, I'm changing the player. This is the best solution in such cases. I'm trying foobar under wine.

Answer (score 11):

I had this problem. Unchecking the Podcast feature in Preferences fixed it. 
Thanks!

Comment: Nice this post helps you too @barry. It's interesting you access the bugs page and click on link "this bugs affect me", it make relevance in priorize correct this bug.  It's not exactly a bug fix IMO because the cost is a funcionallity disabled. I'm gonna check if there's some update of SO/banshee to really fix this bug.

Comment: I've access the banshee's page @barry. The last release was in 2014! I've also seen this is a novell product=too slowly on update software. I'm testing [foobar 2000](http://www.foobar2000.org) running in wine. Until now the  features not working are CD ripping (alternative Assunder CD) and play wma files (I'm converting to mp3 with winff). If the tests gonna be all right, the best solution in my case is change to these softwares. Cheers.

Comment: I unchecked emusic too. Flagged it on launchpad.

I use ripperx for ripping.

Answer (score 1):

:( Unfortunately the next time ( see comments above) I tried to rescan the music library Banshee froze again.

I like to play albums which I browse using cover art - I gave up & tried

1. Rhythmbox - the cover art plugin crashed it
2. Tomahawk - downloads the cover art it can find but doesn't seem to read what's actually there, so it shows a lot of blanks
3. Lollypop - which I liked a lot because you could browse cover art arranged in artist order, but which multiplied compilation albums (& even some non-compilation albums) over many covers with no obvious solution.

So I went back to Banshee. Purged it, deleted the `./config/banshee-1` file, rebooted & then re-installed it. So far so good.

So maybe my problem was buried in the installation or the config file.

Later:

Uh-oh, this seems familiar. this time i repeated the process & deleted the DAAP extension.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problems with Banshee 2.6.2 on Ubuntu 16.04 and 18.04. Unfortunately none of the proposals from above works for me.

I found a very easy workaround. Omit the "Import Media" feature, instead configure the root path of the music collection in Preferences->Source Specific, and then use Menu->Tools->Rescan Music Library.

Answer (score 0):

I had two problems with Banshee in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

1. Freezing on startup
2. Freezing importing media.

Here is how I fixed it and it worked for me.

### If Banshee is freezing when you open it do the following.

Open up your home folder, then in the tool bar above click on edit then preferences. Under the view tab tick the box to (show hidden and backup files) then scroll down and open the folder called .config. Find the folder called banshee-1. and open that folder also and delete all of the files and folders inside. Again go to the tool bar above click on edit then preferences
and under the view tab untick the box to show hidden and backup files, and then close all the windows.

### If your also having problems importing media to the player do the following.

Open the Banshee player then go to the tool bar and click on edit then in the drop-down choose preferences. Click on the extensions tab in the open window and untick everything.

Under the context pain tick wikipedia, under core tick DVD and audio cd support,under utilities tick cover art fetching, library watcher, MPRIS D-Bus interface and sound menu integration.

I tried putting the extensions back to default but it crashed again, I'm not sure whats causing it so as I don't need any more extensions I've left them unticked. As you can see by the screenshot it worked for me.

[Banshee Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TyotN.png)

Comment: As I said in comments above I decided uninstall banshee. His last update was in February 2014 so I've suggested you do the same. I'm using these players: foobar 2000 (for audio, running by wine) , VLC (video), assunder (CD to mp3/ogg) and until now it's fine to me.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue importing media and getting stuck. I then imported the media library source " from Rythembox Player" and it fetched the whole library from rythembox. The only solution till now.